# GORM and foreign key associations

Tags: go

GORM doesn't seem to be honoring my attempt to associate tables based on their foreign key, while the primary key association I have works.

I have 3 structs, that correlate to 3 separate DB tables.  Their relation is as follows:

- Inventory.CustID relates to Customer.CustID *(this association works)*
- GroupRules.RuleContent related to Customer.H1 *(this does not)*

So, my structs are:

```
type Customer struct {
    CustID       sql.NullInt64  `gorm:"primary_key;Column:CUST_ACCT_ID"`
    PlanTypeCd   sql.NullString `gorm:"Column:PLAN_TYPE_CD"`
    H6           sql.NullString `gorm:"Column:H6_CUST_ACCT_NBR"`
    H1           sql.NullString `gorm:"Column:H1_CUST_ACCT_NBR"`
    AddressLine1 sql.NullString `gorm:"Column:ADDRESS_LINE_1"`
    AddressLine2 sql.NullString `gorm:"Column:ADDRESS_LINE_2"`
    City         sql.NullString `gorm:"Column:ADDRESS_CTY_NME"`
    State        sql.NullString `gorm:"Column:ADDRESS_ST_PRVN_CD"`
    Zip          sql.NullString `gorm:"Column:ADDRESS_PSTL_CD"`
    Country      sql.NullString `gorm:"Column:ADDRESS_CTRY_CD"`
}

type Inventory struct {
    CustID            sql.NullInt64  `gorm:"primary_key;Column:CUST_ACCT_ID"`
    CmpntTypeCd       sql.NullString `gorm:"Column:CMPNT_TYPE_CD"`
    AccsBdwdCd        sql.NullString `gorm:"Column:ACCS_BDWD_CD"`
    PrivateLineNumber sql.NullString `gorm:"Column:PRIVATE_LINE_NBR"`
    NtwkUsrAdr        sql.NullString `gorm:"Column:NTWK_USR_ADR"`
    Customer          Customer  `gorm:"association_foreignkey;Column:CUST_ACCT_ID"`
}

type GroupRule struct {
    RuleID           sql.NullInt64  `gorm:"primary_key;Column:RuleID"`
    RuleType         sql.NullString `gorm:"Column:RuleType"`
    RuleContent      sql.NullString `gorm:"Column:RuleContent"`
    RuleLogic        sql.NullString `gorm:"Column:RuleLogic"`
    GroupdID         sql.NullString `gorm:"Column:GroupID"`
    IsActive         sql.NullBool   `gorm:"Column:isActive"`
    LastMatchCount   sql.NullInt64  `gorm:"Column:LastMatchCount"`
    LastMatchPortIds sql.NullString `gorm:"Column:LastMatchPortIDs"`
    Creator          sql.NullInt64  `gorm:"Column:Creator"`
    ExcludeRule      sql.NullBool   `gorm:"Column:ExcludeRule"`
    Customer         Customer  `gorm:"association_foreignkey;Column:H1_CUST_ACCT_ID"`
}
```

Then, my coded relations:

```
cust := Customer{}
inv := Inventory{}
groups := GroupRule{}

DB, e := db.DB{}
// turn on logging
DB.LogMode(true)

// Select * From customers;
DB.Find(&cust)
// gorm association between customers and inventory
DB.Model(&cust).Related(&inv, "CUST_ACCT_ID")
// gorm association between customers and group rules (does not work)
DB.Model(&cust).Related(&groups, "RuleContent")
```

The last association is not working.  Instead, it's still trying to run it's SQL query using the `CUST_ACCT_ID` from `Customer` instead of the foreign key of `H1_CUST_ACCT_ID`.

Log output:

```
// Customer/Inventory relation lookup
SELECT * FROM `Inventory`  WHERE (`CUST_ACCT_ID` = '1439457')

// Customer/GroupRule relation lookup
SELECT * FROM `FON_GroupRules`  WHERE (`RuleContent` = '1439457')
```

In the 2nd lookup, the query should be something like `RuleContent = '9928332').

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just bumped into this.
Did you eventually solve this?

For now I think the GroupRule struct should be

```
type GroupRule struct {
    RuleID           sql.NullInt64  `gorm:"primary_key"`
    RuleType         sql.NullString 
    RuleContent      sql.NullString 
    RuleLogic        sql.NullString 
    GroupdID         sql.NullString 
    IsActive         sql.NullBool   
    LastMatchCount   sql.NullInt64  
    LastMatchPortIds sql.NullString 
    Creator          sql.NullInt64  
    ExcludeRule      sql.NullBool   
    Customer         Customer  `gorm:"foreignKey:RuleContent;references:H1"`
}
```